# How Do Computers Factor Semi-Primes

Tags: cryptography, prime-factorization

How do computers factor large semi-primes? I know it's difficult but what process do they use?  Is it simply a matter of dividing by all odd numbers under the square root of the semi-prime till they get a factor?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: If I want to know whether a four-digit number is prime, I'll check it for divisibility by $3$ and by $5$, but not by $9$ and not by $15$, so "all odd numbers" might be overstated. $\qquad$

Comment: Classic reference is Riesel, http://www.amazon.com/Numbers-Computer-Factorization-Progress-Mathematics/dp/0817637435. It's a couple of decades old and I don't know if it's had recent updates. But it has all the basics of the math and software techniques for serious research into factorization.

Comment: There are entire books written about this topic, so I'm voting to close as too broad.